# Unset or change default "re-detect monitors" windows+p cinnamon keybinding using gsettings

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon, monitors, display, gsettings

I'm trying to unset or change the default `Windows+P` (or to be more exact `Meta+P`) "re-detect monitors" cinnamon keybinding via gsettings, but having a hard time finding it in the gsettings tree.
In the keyboard settings GUI it is shown under System > Devices > Re-detect display (roughly translated from german).

Already went through nearly all of the `org.cinnamon*` and also `org.cinnamon.settings-daemon*` trees, also looked at `org.gnome.settings-daemon*` but can't find it. (Gladly gsettings supports tab completion, otherwise this would be pretty difficult).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a bit more using `gsettings list-recursively` seems I've found the shortcut path. This is it with the default shortcuts under cinnamon 2.8:

> gsettings list-recursively org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.media-keys
>   | grep -i display
>   **org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.media-keys video-outputs** ['p', 'XF86Display']

Removed the pesky `Super+P` default shortcut via
`gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.media-keys video-outputs '["XF86Display"]'` but the change is not reflected in the shortcuts GUI settings until you close it and reopen it.

For completeness sake, most of the default cinnamon keybindings sorted alphabetically by internal name/function can be obtained via
`gsettings list-recursively org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.media-keys | sort -k2` and the ones related to muffin (cinnamon window manager) can be obtained via
`gsettings list-recursively org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm | sort -k2`

---

**EDIT:** Mappings of internal names to the names of the shortcuts shown in the GUI and the mapping of the names from the settings tree in the GUI to the gsettings paths and other valuable information can be obtained from the python script that actually does all the work under the hood:
`/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/modules/cs_keyboard.py`